# No puedo navegar a ruta usando JS en publicacion de IIS C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Tengo un proyecto que he estado creando y lo he publicado en el IIS, ahi todo bien, puedo visualizar mis reportes de Crystal Reports.

Ahora en vuelto a republicar el proyecto (actualizar en el IIS), pero me no puedo ver mis reportes de Crystal Reports que llamo desde js, lo estoy llamando usando esto:

```
var url = "/ReporteIngresoVP/RPVistaPreviaIngreso";
window.open(url, "_blank");
```

A la hora de llamarlo, me abre una pestaña nueva (como deberia ser) y me muestra un 404:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando abro otro reporte (desde el controlador) me muestra el `path`correcto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Según lei por ahi si necesito usar urls que apunten a elementos de `asp.net MVC`deben ir con el `@Url.Action` por eso estoy intentado lo siguiente:

```
var url2='@Url.Action("RPVistaPreviaIngreso","CustomerReporteIngresoVP")';
window.open(url2, "_blank");
```

Pero a la hora de navegar me sale la URL asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo completar la ruta o que pueda ir a la vista que deseo en javascript?

Comment: A ver.. Trata con esta ruta: `IKOR/ReporteIngresoVP/RPVistaPreviaIngreso` creo que te falto la primera parte

Comment: @denifersantiagofernandez no sirve

Comment: Si es un archivo externo de JS recuerda que no renderea Razor, entonces por eso te muestra tal cual la ruta que pones en el string, sugiero que lo dejes de la siguiente manera: `var url2='/CustomerReporteIngresoVP/RPVistaPreviaIngreso`;

Comment: @Phi aunque es correcto, el problema viene a la hora de "publicarlo", el omite el la aplicacion publicada y viaja a esa direccion, por ejemplo mi aplicacion se llama "ikor", cuando navego sin usar js la url es asi `localhost\ikor\xxx\xxx` pero cuando hago eso que me propones queda asi `localhost\xxx\xxx`por lo tanto no encuentra nada, igual ya lo pude resolver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que hice para resolverlo y le puede servir a alguien:

Cree un div que no tiene nada, solo con un `class`y `data-request-url` en este ultimo paso mi `@Url.Action()`

```
<div class="urlPasar" data-request-url="@Url.Action("RPVistaPreviaIngreso","ReporteIngresoVP")"></div>
```

En JS capturar el valor del `data` que esta en el `div`

```
var url = $('.urlPasar').data('request-url');
 window.open(url, "_blank");
```

Funciona tanto para en Visual Studio como en un proyecto publicado

Comment: Interesante truco +1